# Regular Expression to match a list of strings and ignore a list of strings

Tags: java, regex, string

I am looking for a regular expression that meets the below requirement

1. Ignore all the strings that starts with zzTest
2. Match all the strings that contains the word rest and not started with zzTest

Input Strings:

```
zzTest.docs:service1
zzTest.rest:service2
Regression.rest:service1
Regression.docs.service2
```

Expected output:

```
Regression.rest:service1
```

Tried with the regular expression \s*(?!\w*(zzTest)\w*)\w*(rest)\w*\s*
Its works when there is no dot(.) in the input String

Any help appreciated

Comment: Just use `s.matches("(?!zzTest).*rest.*")`

Comment: I really like your solution it is better than mine that is a bit verbose...
@WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Thanks. This worked s.matches("(?!zzTest).*rest.*"). I have modified it to (?!(zzTest|Ignore)).*(rest|api).* to make it work for multiple words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
s.matches("(?!zzTest).*rest.*")
```

The pattern will work as follows:

- `^` - start of string (implicit in `matches`)
- `(?!zzTest)` - not starting with `zzTest`
- `.*rest.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, up to the last `rest` in the line, and then the rest of the line.
- `$` - (implicit in `matches()`): end of string.

To match the whole string, add `(?s)` at the start of the pattern.

To extend it, use alternations:

```
s.matches("(?!zzTest|yyTest|etc).*(?:rest|more here).*")
```

To add whole word matching support, use `\b` around the words:

```
s.matches("(?!\\b(?:zzTest|yyTest|etc)\\b).*\\b(?:rest|more here)\\b.*")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
stringList.stream().filter(s -> !s.startsWith("zzTest")).filter(s -> s.contains("rest"));
```

Although this is not a regular expression solution.

Comment: Why not, it meets the requirements, OP has not mentioned that the words are to be matched as whole words (then, regex would be mandatory).

Comment: Sorry, looking for the regular expression which can configured and update in the future.